# MySQL return nothing if value "0"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL query which under special circumstances returns the value "0" (not NULL) but number 0.

```
SELECT A.user_id as customerref
```

In this case I would like to return an empty value. What is the correct code for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
CASE WHEN a.user_id != 0 THEN a.user_id END AS customerref
```

Answer (score 1):

With `case` :

```
case when A.user_id = 0 then null else A.user_id end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` for this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
   WHEN A.user_id   = 0 THEN NULL
   ELSE A.user_id 
END AS customerref
```